# Using Data Driven Pages, Graphs and selections in ArcMap?

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-10.1, select, data-driven-pages, graph

In ArcMap 10.1 is it possible to create a selection set based on the extent from a Data Driven Page (DDP)?

I have a layout view with a map and a graph.  The graph is set to only plot the selected set of features.  Right now I am paging through the DDP and drawing the selection box manually.  I would like to have the DDP also select point FC within the feature extent.

Comment: What type of data are you using to define the data driven pages?  If you are using polygons, you should be able to iterate through each feature and use that as a basis for select by location.

Comment: No I am not using polygons but I could and then the select by location would be simple to implement.

Answer (score 3):

If your layers have a field that matches a ddp name or page number you can set a definition query on your feature class to include or exclude features that match the ddp

Comment: I have a field in the point FC that I believe might work with this recommendation.  Thanks.